# Entity framework complex query to nested C# object

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

I am having following query here. how do I get similar linq query for this sql.

```
SELECT * 
FROM PublishedLineBar 
WHERE PublishedRosterShiftId 
IN (SELECT LatestShiftId FROM 
       ( SELECT MAX(PublishedRosterShiftId) as LatestShiftId, DayNumber 
         FROM PublishedRosterShift
         WHERE employeeid = 14454
         GROUP BY DayNumber) 
       as ShiftProjection )
```

I have used below linq translation, but it is failing somewhere.

```
var shifts = dbContext.PublishedRosterShifts
                .Where(h => h.EmployeeId == EmployeeId);
var inner = shifts
    .Select(x => new
        {
            LatestShiftId = shifts.Max(p => p.PublishedRosterShiftId),
            DayNumber = x.DayNumber
         })
     .GroupBy(s => s.DayNumber)
     .Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault());
 var q = from f in shifts
     select new
     {
         LatestShiftId = shifts.Max(p => p.PublishedRosterShiftId),
         DayNumber = f.DayNumber
     };
 var query = from l in dbContext.PublishedLineBars
     where inner.Select(s => s.LatestShiftId).Contains(l.PublishedRosterShiftId)
     select l;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the LINQ equivalent of your subquery used for SQL `IN (...)` clause (with unnecessary nesting removed):

```
var inner = dbContext.PublishedRosterShifts
    .Where(s => s.EmployeeId == EmployeeId)
    .GroupBy(s => s.DayNumber)
    .Select(g => g.Max(s => s.PublishedRosterShiftId));
```

and the query using it:

```
var query = from l in dbContext.PublishedLineBars
            where inner.Contains(l.PublishedRosterShiftId)
            select l;
```

or simply

```
var query = dbContext.PublishedLineBars
    .Where(l => inner.Contains(l.PublishedRosterShiftId));
```

What you are missing in your attempt is that in SQL `SELECT MAX(PublishedRosterShiftId) as LatestShiftId, DayNumber` operates on the result of the `GROUP BY` operator, hence in LINQ the `Select` should be after `GroupBy`.

Comment: Thanks alot. That helped. :)